# Name for SELECT equivalent of UPSERT

Tags: t-sql, select, naming-convention, upsert

`UPSERT` means `INSERT` and\or `UPDATE`, is there a standard name for a stored procedure that will `INSERT` if necessary and then `SELECT`?

e.g.  I want to get the IS of a row that matches columns and give me the ID, if nothing matched then I want it to `INSERT` a new row and return me the ID of that row.

Comment: Similar question has been answered here.


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593870/select-insert-version-of-an-upsert-is-there-a-design-pattern-for-high-concurr

Comment: @BinayaRegmi, that question seems to be about implementation (which is useful as well), I just wondered if thare was a naming convention for it...  `Merge` maybe?

Comment: `MERGE` is the actual SQL statement that performs the "upsert" function. I don't think there is a name for what you are describing. May be call it "inselect"?

Comment: In other contexts, that would look like a `get or create` pattern. The naming, obviously, is not very much *SQLish*.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL we have a name for it [`INSERT ... RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).

You can use this form in a `CTE` to obtain the effect you want..

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( foo serial, bar int );


WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT x
  FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(x)
),
t2 AS (
  INSERT INTO foo (bar)
  SELECT x
  FROM t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM foo
    WHERE foo.bar = x
  )
  RETURNING foo, bar
)
SELECT foo, bar
FROM foo
INNER JOIN t1 ON (foo.bar = t1.x)
UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM t2
;
```

Here we

1. Generate test data in a cte `t1` which we plan to `INSERT` or `SELECT` on.
2. With `t2` we `INSERT` the data we don't already have into our desired table... `foo`, and return the results (that which was inserted) as `t2`
3. We run a `SELECT` to get all of the elements in our test data (`t1`) that already exist.
4. `INSERT` all of the others.